# Only one UILabel value is being saved

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a simple app, which consists of 2 UILabels and a button to add the value of both of them together.  I am using `NSUserdefaults` to save the values of the labels when exiting the app/hitting the back button/app crashes etc.  I am calling this save function when selecting the button which adds both values together.

The problem I am having is that only 1 of the UILabel values is being saved the other isn't. I've tried all sorts of tweaking but can't get to the bottom of it.

Here is my h file code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int dcounter;
int dtotaler;
int enteramount;

@interface durood : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *dcount;
    IBOutlet UILabel *dtotal;
    IBOutlet UITextField *numberTextField;

}

-(IBAction)addtotal1;
```

Here is the code from my m file:

```
-(IBAction)addtotal1;{

    float x = ([dcount.text floatValue]);
    float y = ([dtotal.text floatValue]);
    [dtotal setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", x + y]];
    dcounter=0;
    dcount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",dcounter];
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",dtotaler] forKey:@"saveDtotal"];
    [userDefaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dcounter] forKey:@"saveDcount"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

-(void)saveDcount
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dcounter] forKey:@"saveDcount"];
    [userDefaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dtotaler] forKey:@"saveDtotal"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveDcount) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveDcount) name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveDtotal) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveDtotal)   name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification object:nil];



    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *dcountString= [userDefaults objectForKey:@"saveDcount"];
    NSLog(@"Your Dcount: %@",dcount);
    NSString *dtotalString= [userDefaults objectForKey:@"saveDtotal"];
    NSLog(@"Your Dtotal: %@",dtotal);

    //checking if data in user defaults is not empty
    if(dcountString.length>0)
    {
        dcounter=[dcountString intValue];
        dcount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dcounter];

    }
    else
    {
        //for first time
        dcounter=0;
        dcount.text=@"0";
    }

    if(dtotalString.length>0)
    {
        dtotaler=[dtotalString intValue];
        dtotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dtotaler];
    }
    else
    {
        //for first time
        dtotaler=0;
        dtotal.text=@"0";
    }
}
```

The UILabel / string which is NOT saving is 'dtotal'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: where is your `saveDtotal` method? and you will get compile error if your .h file is included by more than one .m file. you have to make `int dcounter;` to `extern int dcounter;` and such. or you should move then to .m file

Comment: I have not pasted my entire m file, the -void saveDcount includes code to save Dtotal also

Comment: Use the debugger or add NSLog statements to print out all of the variables you are setting in `addTotal1`.  Do all of these values reflect what you expect?

Comment: then show us `saveDtotal`, because it is the method to save `dtotal` right?

Comment: @xlc the -void saveDcount includes code to save Dtotal also, I did separate them when tweaking but it made no difference

Comment: @SeamusCampbell I ran the app in the simulator and I get these responses when I come out and then go into the app:

NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x76733b0>>
2013-04-07 02:16:40.165 Tapcount[7864:11303] Your Dcount: <UILabel: 0x757cc00; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x757c880>>
2013-04-07 02:16:40.165 Tapcount[7864:11303] Your Dtotal: <UILabel: 0x7578470; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x75a4660>>

Comment: I don't see anywhere where dtotal ever gets updated from the text value of dtotaler.

Comment: its responses are more or less same as dcount, but dcount is saving

Comment: Why is your "data model" a set of strings and labels when you should be working with numbers (`float`)? Save numbers to `NSUserDefaults`. Add two numbers. Save the result in a number. Use the labels only to display the numbers. Never use views as your data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this.

```
-(IBAction)addtotal1;{

float x = ([dcount.text floatValue]);
float y = ([dtotal.text floatValue]);
dtotaler = x + y;
dtotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dtotaler];
dcounter=0;
dcount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",dcounter];
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dtotaler] forKey:@"saveDtotal"];
[userDefaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",dcounter] forKey:@"saveDcount"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Thanks for everyone's input.